# Monotonically increasing sequences in $[0,\infty]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I want to prove that any monotonically increasing sequence $(x_n)$ of extended real numbers converges to $\sup_{n} x_n$ (with respect to the order topology) .

There are two cases, either $(x_n)$ is bounded by some (positive) real number $M$ or not.
It's okay for the first case, using least-upper-bound property. But I stuck on the second one.

When the sequence $(x_n)$ is unbounded by a real, it means that for any positive real number $M$, there is some integer $n$ such that $x_n > M$. I want to show that $x_n \to \infty$.

Let $V_\infty$ be a neighborhood of $\infty$. I stuck a bit at this step, I want to show that there exists a positive real $M$ for which $]M, \infty]\subseteq V_\infty$. Since $(x_n)$ is increasing and unbounded, there will be some $n_0$ such that for any $n\geqslant n_0$, we have $x_n\geqslant x_{n_0}>M$, then $x_n \in V_\infty$ and we are done.

How to get the existence of at least one $M$ such that $]M,\infty] \subseteq V_\infty$ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how the topology of the extended real numbers is defined?

Comment: Yes, it's generated by intervals of the form $[-\infty,a[$ and $]b, \infty]$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R$... but I don't see how to use this fact :/

Comment: that is a sub-basis right?

Comment: can you tell me what the elements of the basis that contain $\infty$ look like?

Comment: Ah... set of the form $]b,\infty]$...

Comment: yes, remember that the basis is formed by the finite intersections of elements of the basis. Indeed you are correct. It should be easy to conclude from here right?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77587/discussion-between-phoenix-and-jorge-fernandez).

Answer (score 1):

What you have to prove is that for any open neighborhood $O$ of $\infty$, there is $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $x_n \in O$. If $O$ is an open set containing $\infty$, then by definition (of a basis of a topology), there is some $b\in \mathbb R$ such that $(b,\infty] \subset O$. Conclude.